# MLE for the sum of independent Bernoulli trials with common factor

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Suppose I am computing the sum of different bernoulli trials with probability $p_i = P s_i$, where $P$ is a common factor to all trials and $s_i$ is given, how can I compute the MLE for $P$? I realize this a special case of the Poisson binomial distribution, but since I want the MLE for a single value rather than a sequence, I'd hope the problem is easier, still I haven't been able to reach a solution.

Comment: I think there is no closed form solution to this. The equation I have needs solving the following: $$\frac{m}{P}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-m}\frac{s_j}{1-Ps_j}=0$$ where $m$ is the number of positive outcomes in the data, and the sum is across negative examples. This is an $n-m+1$-th order polynomial and can be solved numerically given the data.